# Converting JSON response string to a UWP gridview datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, uwp

I have the following code that successfully retrieves a JSON string from a database. I now want to display this information in a gridview on the client side though im not sure how to do this.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string strJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(strJson);
    //apply to my grid view
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deserialize object eg. with newtonsoft library. To do that use attributes or create deserializer manually, but you have to create a class or structure which represents database data.

If eg. your json looks like this :

```
{
  "Name":"Aleks",
  "City": "N.Y."
}
```

Try to create class:

```
public class Person{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}  
}
```

And in your condition

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
string strJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(strJson);
Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(strJson);    
}
```

To show it at GridView you have to declare GridView in xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="test" DataTemplate="{StaticResource YourTemplate}"/>
```

And in codebehind

```
 test.ItemSource = new List<Preson>(){person};
```

DataTemplate is also needed.

```
<GridView x:Name="test">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
   <TextBlock Text{Binding Name}/>
   <TextBlock Text{Binding City}/>
  </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(strJson);  
//Binding gridview from dynamic object   
grdView.DataSource = myObject;  
grdView.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How to do in UWP ?